# #define woes – the macro that isn't

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm trying to do something like:

```
#define __attribute__((aligned(2))) __attribute__((space(prog),aligned(2)))
```

but the compiler yields :

```
 error: "(" may not appear in macro parameter list
```

Questions:  What gives? How can I do a literal text replace, no bells, no frills ?

Comment: Are you missing a closing bracket? `#define __attribute__((aligned(2))) __attribute__((space(prog),aligned(2)))`?

Comment: thanks for the comment but nope, even without the blunder the compiler craps out with the same error.

Comment: yeah your parens don't match up

Comment: It has to do with the nested ((( I think

Comment: Since the OP doesn't appear to have enough rep to edit their question, I have added the missing parenthesis for them.

Comment: I think @honk is rigth. Without that bracket, you are making a recursive definition (__attribute__ is required to define __attribute__)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the C preprocessor.  You can only define "literal txt replace"s, as you put it, if the text you want to replace is a single identifier ("object-like macro" in C standard parlance). What you wrote causes the preprocessor to think you're trying to define a "function-like macro", with a *parameter* named "`(aligned(2))`", which is a syntax error.

I would deal with this problem by wrapping the entire `__attribute__` construct in an object-like macro:

```
#if appropriate condition
#define ATTRIBUTE_ALIGNED_2 __attribute__((space(prog),aligned(2)))
#else
#define ATTRIBUTE_ALIGNED_2 __attribute__((aligned(2)))
#endif
```

and then replacing `__attribute__((aligned(2)))` with `ATTRIBUTE_ALIGNED_2` throughout the source code.

Comment: Ha! Look at how I solved it :#define __attribute__(x)  __attribute__((space(prog),aligned(2)))

Comment: ... that'll work as long as nobody wants to use any of GCC's *other* attribute extensions, but the first time someone puts `__attribute__((noreturn))` on a function, kaboom.

Comment: isn't the define only scoped for this file?

Comment: If you put it in one source file, yes -- but then why not just fix the uses in that file?  If it's in a header file, everything that includes that header gets it.  You sounded like you were trying to do a project-wide adjustment.

Comment: Cool. Well, see the problem is I'm trying to fix a source file generated by an executable blob, so .. Yeah, I prefer spending a bit of time developing defines that auto-fix the generated .c instead of find->replace each time.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  Your approach is fine, then, but have you considered adding a build step that edits the generated .c file?  Using `sed`, or Perl, or whatever's convenient.  That'll be a lot more flexible than what the C preprocessor lets you do.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you start with a parenthesis, you're defining a macro with arguments, and that's bound to some rules.

So you can do, for example:

```
#define succ(x) (x + 1)
```

But you can't do:

```
#define pred(x + 1) x
```

The preprocessor only does a very limited set of pattern matching.

What you *could* do instead is something like:

```
#define __aligned2__ __attribute__((space(prog),aligned(2)))
```

And use that define instead. If that's not sufficient for your needs, you'll need to do some custom preprocessing using `sed` instead.